# Get list or array property from object to DataGridView via BindingList

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindinglist

I have only been able to get string properties from (in this example) the object "Person" to fill in the datagridview cells (one object for each row). But I need to dynamically create these properties using multiple values (multiple cells) belonging to a property with the same name as defined in DataGridView's DataPropertyName. Like this:

The reason for this is that I need to bind an object to each row to manipulate it later. I've tried to use Array, but each cell in DataGridView DataPropertyName requires a property with a name. Resulting in one cell containing the text "String[] Array". I also don't know if or how to put a DataPropertyName in an array followed by the cell values.

Is it possible to use Dictionary here, or something else?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.ColumnId.DataPropertyName = "Id";
    this.ColumnFirstName.DataPropertyName = "FirstName";

    List <Person> list = new List<Person>();
    list.Add(new Person());

    BindingList<Person> persons = new BindingList<Person>(list);
    persons.AllowNew = true;

    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = persons;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
}
```

The Person class (the code is just an example):

```
public class Person
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> lista = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public Person()
    {
        lista.Add("Id", "Identifikator");
        lista.Add("FirstName", "Fornavn");
    }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Lista
    {
        get
        {
            return lista;
        }
        set
        {
            lista = value;
        }
    }
}
```